# Cant find class when using "Whoops!" library?

Tags: php, whoops

Recently I have been trying the Whoops! library and trying to get it to work, however, unfortunately this is the closest I have gotten to get it working.

I installed it via the composer using this tutorial
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/whoops-php-errors-for-cool-kids--net-32344

PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

# index.php
require(getcwd() . "/vendor/autoload.php");

$whoops = new Whoops\Run();
$whoops->pushHandler(new Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler());

// Set Whoops as the default error and exception handler used by PHP:
$whoops->register();

throw new RuntimeException("Oopsie!");
?>
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Whoops\Run' not found in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CMS\app\library\whoops\index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CMS\app\library\whoops\index.php on line 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code and it ran fine for me (it actually did nothing, but the class loaded just fine).  Check your composer.json and ensure it has:

```
{
    "name": "root/stack-overflow",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "filp/whoops": "1.*"
    }
}
```

Run `composer update` just to be sure.  And lastly ensure that your index.php is in the directory that has vendor as a subdirectory.

Comment: It didn't have your composer code it just had "{ }" although when I updated my composer.json to yours and ran composer update in the directory the composer.json was located it threw an error.

"./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 1:
  "require": {    "flip/whoops
  --------^
  Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'

Comment: OK, I'll update with the whole file...this should work.  This is what you get when you run composer require filp/whoops 1.* (at least the require part).

Answer (score 0):

`Whoops` `namespace` is either missing or it does not have a `Run` `class`. Check **autoload.php** and make sure it loads `Whoops` and the `Whoops` you are using has the `Run` `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the provided example at https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/whoops-php-errors-for-cool-kids--net-32344   which you can see loads /vendor/autoload.php slightly differently.

The error suggest that the Whoops class is not being properly loaded.

```
<?php
# index.php
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$whoops = new Whoops\Run();
$whoops->pushHandler(new Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler());

// Set Whoops as the default error and exception handler used by PHP:
$whoops->register();  

throw new RuntimeException("Oopsie!");
?>`
```

OK.  Check that your paths are correct and that /vendor/ does contain whoops.
the tree should be something like

-vendor

--Whoops

--autoload.php

-index.php

Comment: This outputs the same error, didn't change anything.

Comment: OK.  Check that your paths are correct and that /vendor/ does contain whoops.
I have put the comment in the answer as i cannot format it here.

Basically it looks like to me it is not loading Whoops correctly.